# Why didn't Kabuto resurrect Jiraiya during the Great War?

Tags: naruto

During the Great War, Kabuto resurrects a lot of very, very powerful shinobi (Madara or Hashirama the 1st, e.g.). However, he doesn't bring someone as powerful and impactful as Jiraiya.

My girlfriend pointed this out a few days ago and since now, I wasn't able to find a reason. I see that this *Edo Tensei no Jutsu* brings up some questions ([about more Uchiha's](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/38187/why-is-there-no-reanimated-uchiha-fighting-in-fourth-shinobi-war) or even [Orochimaru](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4955/why-didnt-couldnt-kabuto-bring-orochimaru-back)) on the table, but it seems that everyone forgot Jiraiya in this equation.

Why didn't Kabuto resurrect Jiraiya during the Great War?

Comment: Why do I feel that Jiraiya might return in Boruto series?

Comment: I'm not even trying to watch this serie, considering the ABSURD amount of fillers in Shippuden's last arc ... I feel they try to milk the franchise up to its last drop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, this case of Jiraiya's resurrection had been brought up by Kabuto while discussing the secrets of the Edo Tensei  with Obito. He had also mentioned about Shisui Uchiha.

The reason as to why Jiraiya *couldn't be* revived according to [Naruto Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Jiraiya):

> When the Fourth Shinobi World War starts, Kabuto Yakushi expresses interest in reincarnating Jiraiya to have him fight for Akatsuki, but unfortunately is unable to reach him **as his body rests in the lower depths of the sea**.

But in the manga, Kabuto expresses that he could obtain enough DNA (to revive Jiraiya) from the weapons used by the Paths in their fight against Jiraiya. But Obito comments not to push his luck, as reviving Jiraiya, as well as Shisui, could be overkill.

*Naruto* chapter 520, page 14:

[image]

Comment: I find this a rather weak reason not to get his body tho ... Very well, thank you !

Comment: @YassineBadache: While that's true, Obito actually didn't have any need for them. He had mainly, Madara on his side, and also Itachi. Glad that you're satisfied with my answer.

Comment: Your answer is very accurate, I'm just really dissapointed that this is the main reason ... Knowing the emotionnal break that it would cause, I'd go for it 100%. Anyway, guess we're done here.

Comment: Rather than overkill, the main reason that Obito rejected the idea is that the alliance was temporary and Obito was pretty much forced into it after Kabuto showed edo-tensei-ed Uchiha M. He didn't trust Kabuto, thus addng extra weapon for Kabuto would be a bad idea for him.

Answer (score 1):

There was not much left of him.

When Tsunade was explaining the circumstances to Naruto when he returned from a mission, he wanted to bring the body back. However, because of Konans' explosion jutsu and the dangers of going to retrieve it and the boiling oil jutsu he himself used, there wasn't much left to salvage and bring back to the Hidden Leaf.

Kabuto would have had even less time as the remains were decomposing by the time he realized Jiraya was indeed dead.

Comment: -1 Jiraiya's body was pretty much intact when he decided to fall into the depth of the ocean. I think you are mistaking the scene where Konan fought Obito with the scene where Jiraiya fought Pain.

Answer (score 1):

The anime episode that refers to why Jiraiya Sensei couldn't be used for the reanimation, is episode 264 of Shippuden, in season 5. The explanation of starts around 17 minutes of the episode.

Comment: Answers should address the question, not just tell people to watch or read a particular episode or chapter. Furthermore, if there is already an accepted answer, new answers should either: contradict the previous answer or not contradict it but provide new information.